# Android parsing plist strings and integers

Tags: android, parsing, plist

hi i'm trying to parse a plist in android i have using a modified version of KPBirds plist parser found here http://kpbird.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/android-plist-parser.html

problem is i have everything set up with no errors but when i run it it trys to parse strings through as integers. for example: name is setup as a string and it comes through saying name cannot be parsed as an integer.

any ideas as to why?

heres my code so far the way it works is in my activity i run a function that gets the reads the plist then applies a data model to it and then should log it in log cat.

heres the error

```
09-02 10:49:44.717: E/AndroidRuntime(1736): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'image1' as integer
09-02 10:49:44.717: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
09-02 10:49:44.717: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
09-02 10:49:44.717: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
09-02 10:49:44.717: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at co.uk.luke.ParsePlist.parsePlist(ParsePlist.java:68)
09-02 10:49:44.717: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at co.uk.luke.LevelSelect.readPlistContents(LevelSelect.java:63)
09-02 10:49:44.717: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at co.uk.luke.LevelSelect.onCreate(LevelSelect.java:91)
09-02 10:49:44.717: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
09-02 10:49:44.717: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
```

heres my activity where i call the function

```
/// Read plist from Assets
        private String readPlistFromAssets() {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader br=null;
            try {
                 br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("Levels.plist"))); 
                String temp;
                while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                    sb.append(temp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    br.close(); // stop reading
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }


        public void readPlistContents(){
            // Read Plist content
            String xml = readPlistFromAssets();
            // create object of Parser Class
            ParsePlist pp = new ParsePlist();
            // parse Plist and fill in plist array
            ArrayList<DataModel> plist = pp.parsePlist(xml);
            // Print ArrayList
            Iterator<DataModel> i = plist.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext()){
                DataModel d = i.next();
                Log.i("Plist","=========================");
                Log.i("Plist","Levelid = " + d.getLevelid());
                Log.i("Plist","title = " + d.getTitle());
                Log.i("Plist","name = " + d.getName());
                Log.i("Plist","lockStatus = " + d.getLockStatus());
                Log.i("Plist","total = " + d.getTotal());
                Log.i("Plist","totalCompleted = " + d.getTotalCompleted());
                Log.i("Plist","Points = " + d.getPoints());
                Log.i("Plist","Image = " + d.getImage());

            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Parsing completed please check logcat...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

heres my data model

```
public class DataModel {

    private String title;
    private String name;
    private String levelid;
    private String lockStatus;
    private int total;
    private int totalCompleted;
    private int Points;
    private String Image;


    public int getTotaCompleted() {
        return totalCompleted;
    }
    public void setTotalCompleted(int totalCompleted) {
        this.totalCompleted = totalCompleted;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
    public void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return Points;
    }
    public void setPoints(int Points) {
        this.Points = Points;
    }



    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getLevelid() {
        return levelid;
    }
    public void setLevelid(String levelid) {
        this.levelid = levelid;
    }
    public String getLockStatus() {
        return lockStatus;
    }
    public void setLockStatus(String lockStatus) {
        this.lockStatus = lockStatus;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return Image;
    }
    public void setImage(String Image) {
        this.Image = Image;
    }


}
```

heres the code where i parse the plist

```
public class ParsePlist {


    // parse Plist and fill in arraylist
    public ArrayList<DataModel> parsePlist(String xml) {
        final ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
        //Get the xml string from assets

        final Document doc = XMLfromString(xml);

        final NodeList nodes_array = doc.getElementsByTagName("array");

        //Fill in the list items from the XML document
        for ( int index = 0; index < nodes_array.getLength(); index++ ) {

            final Node node = nodes_array.item(index);

            if ( node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ) {
                final Element e = (Element)nodes_array.item(index);

                final NodeList nodeKey = e.getElementsByTagName("key");
                final NodeList nodeString = e.getElementsByTagName("string");
                DataModel model = new DataModel();

                for (int i=0; i<nodeString.getLength(); i++) {

                    final Element eleKey = (Element)nodeKey.item(i);
                    final Element eleString = (Element)nodeString.item(i);


                    if ( eleString != null ) {

                        String strValue = getValue(eleString, "string");


                        if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("title")) {
                            model = new DataModel();
                            model.setTitle(strValue);

                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("name")) {
                            model.setName(strValue);

                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("levelid")) {
                            model.setLevelid(strValue); 


                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("lockStatus")) {
                            model.setLockStatus(strValue);  

                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("total")) {
                            model.setTotal(Integer.parseInt(strValue));

                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("totalCompleted")) {
                            model.setTotalCompleted(Integer.parseInt(strValue));


                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("Points")) {
                            model.setPoints(Integer.parseInt(strValue));

                        } else if(getValue(eleKey, "key").equals("Image")) {
                            model.setImage(strValue);   


                            dataModels.add(model);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dataModels;
    }

    // Create xml document object from XML String
    private  Document XMLfromString(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

    // fetch value from Text Node only
    private   String getElementValue(Node elem) {
        Node kid;
        if (elem != null) {
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling()) {
                    if (kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return kid.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    /// Fetch value from XML Node
    private   String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

and finally heres my plist

```
<key>title</key>
        <string>ZONE1</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>LEVEL 1</string>
        <key>levelid</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>lockStatus</key>
        <string>UNLOCKED</string>
        <key>total</key>
        <integer>20</integer>
        <key>totalCompleted</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Points</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>Image</key>
        <string>image1</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 final NodeList nodeKey = e.getElementsByTagName("key");
 final NodeList nodeString = e.getElementsByTagName("string");
```

After add

final NodeList nodeInteger = e.getElementsByTagName("integer");

add after the line  in second for loop

```
final Element eleString = (Element)nodeString.item(i);

 final Element eleInteger = (Element)nodeInteger .item(i);
```

then check another if condition

```
if ( eleInteger != null ) {

 String strValue = getValue(eleInteger, "integer");

}
```

Comment: do i add this to anywhere as it currently says noteInteger is unused

Comment: again i can't just add that because it not being used anywhere i need to call the eleinteger somewhere